# Mapping LOB Data in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

In my Spring Boot app, I want to keep some text fields e.g. `comment` and as far as I know, I can use `@Lob` or `columnDefinition = "TEXT"` feature in the related Entity column. There are some pros and cons, but I am not sure which one is suitable for using PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQL Server.

So, should I use `@Lob` or `columnDefinition = "TEXT"` ? And is the following usage a proper usage for each of these?

```
@Lob
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
private String instructions;
```

or

```
@Column(name = "body", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String body;
```

And should I also use `columnDefinition` with `@Lob`? If so, should its value be "TEXT" or "CLOB"?

Comment: I can comment here that `Lob` and `TEXT` do _not_ do the same thing in Postgres.

Comment: @Tim Could you explain a little bit more and share your opinion about the most proper one for this scenario?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And should I also use `columnDefinition` with `@Lob`? If so, should its value be "TEXT" or "CLOB"?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What would you suggest chico?

Comment: The behavior is different on each database.  If you want an answer here, you should specify your actual database.

Comment: PostgreSQL or MySQL.